# Generating Stego-Video results in losing embedded data in frame

Tags: python, video, video-processing, steganography, dct

I'm have worked on extracting frames from a video and tested code from GitHub (
https://github.com/MasonEdgar/DCT-Image-Steganography.) to perform DCT on frame to hide secret text data. I then tried to generate a stego-video with embedded frame but I noticed I was not able to successfully extract data after generating stego-video.

I'm not sure why I wasn't able to extract the message but I'm assuming the regeneration of the video has caused the issue.

Is there a way to generate the video without losing the embedded data ? like should I use opencv or any other library ?

I'm still fairly new to implementing video steganography and using Python as well.

The code below has been used to generate the video.

```
import os
import moviepy.video.io.ImageSequenceClip
from natsort import natsorted
image_folder='frame_folder'
fps=25
image_files = [image_folder+'/'+img for img in os.listdir(image_folder) if img.endswith(".png")]
sorted_ima= natsorted(image_files)
clip = moviepy.video.io.ImageSequenceClip.ImageSequenceClip(sorted_ima, fps=fps)
clip.write_videofile('steg_video.mp4')
```

**Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: What do you mean "perform DCT on frame to hide text data"? I have a suspicion you take an image (frame), get the DCT coefficients, modify them, IDCT to get pixels again and that's your stego frame. If you do that, you have to use a lossless video codec, which mp4 isn't, because that affects your pixel values and by extend your DCT coefficients.

Comment: @Reti43 Yes I did the process you mentioned. Thank you for answering my question and addressing that my assumption was correct.